# Group by mysql adicionando valores null

Tags: mysql, sql

Como eu posso adicionar valores vazios no `group by`?

**Exemplo:**

Eu tenho uma consulta que é organizada por idades:

```
 CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4' 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5 a 9 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 10 AND 17 THEN '10 a 17 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18 a 24 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 29 THEN '25 a 29 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 a 39 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 a 49 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 a 59 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60 a 69 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) >= 70 THEN 'Maior que 70 Anos'
        ELSE 'SEM INFORMAÇÕES'  END
```

Mas quando os valores não tem resultados eles não constam no select, eu queria adicionar 0 em todas essas opções do `CASE`.

Meu select todo para referência:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4' 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5 a 9 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 10 AND 17 THEN '10 a 17 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18 a 24 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 29 THEN '25 a 29 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 a 39 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 a 49 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 a 59 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60 a 69 Anos'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) >= 70 THEN 'Maior que 70 Anos'
        ELSE 'SEM INFORMAÇÕES'  END , 
        COUNT(id)
        FROM pessoas GROUP BY DataNascimento
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A não ser que na sua tabela exista, pelo menos um registo para cada um dos casos indicados, a forma como abordou o seu problema não irá produzir o resultado desejado. Neste caso em particular, o COALESCE, não vai ajudar.

No seu caso parece óbvio que o problema é que, para algumas das faixas etárias apresentadas, não existe uma pessoa com idade no intervalo respectivo.

Eu normalmente resolvo situações semelhantes usando uma tabela temporária ou uma sub-query onde listo explicitamente todas as categorias (neste caso faixa etária). Depois é apenas uma questão de usar o `LEFT JOIN` para obter os resultados

Deixo aqui uma implementação usando uma sub-query

```
SELECT  Categorias.Cat,
        ISNULL(NumPessoas, 0) NumPessoas
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 'Menos de 4'   AS Cat,       1 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '5 a 9 Anos'   AS Cat,       2 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '10 a 17 Anos' AS Cat,       3 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '18 a 24 Anos' AS Cat,       4 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '25 a 29 Anos' AS Cat,       5 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '30 a 39 Anos' AS Cat,       6 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '40 a 49 Anos' AS Cat,       7 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '50 a 59 Anos' AS Cat,       8 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT '60 a 69 Anos' AS Cat,       9 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Maior que 70 Anos' AS Cat, 10 AS Ordenacao UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SEM INFORMAÇÕES' AS Cat,   11 AS Ordenacao 
  ) Categorias
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  FaixaEtaria,
            COUNT(DISTINCT id) NumPessoas
    FROM        
    (
        SELECT  id,
                CASE 
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/% Y'),CURDATE()) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4' 
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5 a 9 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 10 AND 17 THEN '10 a 17 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN '18 a 24 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 29 THEN '25 a 29 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30 a 39 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40 a 49 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50 a 59 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60 a 69 Anos'
                    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'),CURDATE()) >= 70 THEN 'Maior que 70 Anos'
                    ELSE 'SEM INFORMAÇÕES'  
                END FaixaEtaria, 
        FROM pessoas 
    ) iRes
    GROUP BY FaixaEtaria
) Resultados
   ON Resultados.FaixaEtaria = Categorias.Cat
ORDER BY Categorias.Ordenacao
```

Comment: isso funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 2):

Se "Mas quando os valores não tem resultados eles não constam no select" forem valores `NULL`. O MySQL contém uma função chamada [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Ela retorna o primeiro valor não `null` da consulta. Caso não enconte nenhum você pode especificar o valor que queria mostrar, por exemplo:

```
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    YEAR,
    COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(DataNascimento, '%d/%m/%Y'), 0),
    CURDATE()
) < 4 THEN 'Menos de 4'
```

Neste caso atenderia a este `WHEN < 4`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso me ajudou muito era exatamente oque eu estava procurando, esqueci do coalesce, deixa eu te perguntar e no caso do else do case, como eu posso utilizar o coalesce?

Comment: acho que tem alguma coisa errada pq eu utilizo o count(id) e nao conta como 0 os valores que nao aparecem na consulta

Comment: Na verdade tudo que ele não encontrar será setado pelo coalesce como 0. Seguindo a lógica nunca cairá no else, pois o primeiro `WHEN` é `< 4`. Se mesmo assim cair no `ELSE` seria interessante verificar registro por registros que estão caindo nessa condição

Comment: Eu tenho registros com 99/99/9999, so que eu preciso que quando nao tenha nenhuma valor < 4 por exemplo ele preencha 0 e nao esta fazendo isso

Comment: O correto seria tratar essa informação via alteração em banco, pois, como bem sabe não existe essa data. Altere esses valores para `null`.

Comment: o meu problema maior nao e esse, e sim quando nao tem nenhum valor ele nao coloca como 0

Comment: Ainda continua sendo problema de formatação de dados no banco. Na hora de salvar necessita ter uma tratativa, um padrão, para aplicar quando os dados a serem salvos vierem vazios. Ainda continua sendo o caso de setar como `null`.

Comment: Mesmo eu setando como null continua nao aparecendo o 0 quando nao tem o valor

Comment: Eu fiz o teste no banco e deu certo. Adicionei a imagem na resposta para ver. Caso tenha alterado o valor na não, o banco entenderá como uma string null não um campo do tipo null. Aplique a alteração através do comando UPDATE e set o valor como null.

Comment: O meu problema e que não vem esse null, eu quero preencher os valores que não vem com essas opções
EX:
table pessoas
id 1, DataNascimento 10/10/2015
id 2, DataNascimento 20/02/2000
nao vai aparecer as outras opções somente <4 e 10 a 17 Anos eu quero que mostre todas essas opções e de o cont(id) 0

Comment: A resposta não adressa o problema do @GuilhermeFreire. O uso do COALESCE não vai produzir o resultado desejado.